# I need to find the maximum amount of edges in graph so that it's subgraph is a forest. But my code shows double the result

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I'm solving a problem where given any cactus graph, I need to find the maximum amount of edges its subgraph can have so that the subgraph is a forest. The catch is: if vertices 0 and 1 form an edge in the graph, they must also in the subgraph. I have a graph and a test cactus subgraph, this graph is 3 triangles, conected at vertex 2, it should show 9 edges and the resulting subgraph should have 3 edges. The result is printing 18 edges and 6 in the subgraph.

```
    def max_edges_in_forest(cactus_graph, num_vertices):
    max_edges = 0

    for root in range(num_vertices):
        visited = [False] * num_vertices
        num_components = 0
        num_edges = 0

        def dfs(vertex):
            nonlocal num_components, num_edges
            visited[vertex] = True
            num_components += 1

            for neighbor in cactus_graph[vertex]:
                if not visited[neighbor]:
                    num_edges += 1  # Increment edge count only for new edges
                    dfs(neighbor)

        dfs(root)
        max_edges = max(max_edges, num_edges)

    return max_edges

# Example usage
cactus_graph = [[1,2], [0,2], [0,1,3,4,5,6], [2,4],[2,3],[2,6],[2,5]]
num_vertices = 7
num_edges = sum(len(adj_list) for adj_list in cactus_graph)
max_edges = max_edges_in_forest(cactus_graph, num_vertices)
print("Number of edges in the cactus graph:", num_edges)
print("Maximum number of edges in the forest subgraph:", max_edges)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the edges selected in the DFS and drawing them?

Comment: The problem statement is unclear. Could you paste in the exact problem you were given?

Comment: A cactus is a generalization of a single tree to allow some cycles. Is there a difference between the problem you state and the problem of finding the minimum number of edges to remove to *obtain* a tree? (I'm not sure the forest you want to find would ever contain more than one tree.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason your program isn't doing what you want is because you're double counting every edge. For example, with an edge between the nodes 0 and 1, you count it once from 0 going to 1 and again from 1 going to 0. All you need to do is `num_edges = num_edges // 2`.

However, from the way you described the problem, your answer to the example is wrong. You could just remove the edges: (0, 2), (2, 6), (2, 4). Leaving you with a tree (forest) of 6 edges (which is greater than what you said should be the answer). I might not be correctly understanding the problem and if I am i apologise.

If i am right, here is what I came up with:

```py
def max_edges_in_forest(cactus_graph):
    seen = set()
    count = 0

    def search(node, previous):
        nonlocal count
        seen.add(node)
        for neighbour in cactus_graph[node]:
            if neighbour == previous:
                continue
            if neighbour not in seen:
                count += 1
                search(neighbour, node)
    search(0, 0)
    return count
```